# Styled-components and Storybook should be used together?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, storybook, react-tsx

Since Styled-component purpose is having a clean code without "className={}", "class={}" on my code, how can I use it with Storybook?

For example, if I have a button that's gray and I need a red-error-variant, on Storybook I should have something like:

```
<Button className={error} label='That's an error!'> </Button>
```

But with styled-components I should create a:

```
const ErrorButton = styled.button`
background-color: red;
`

    On JSX:
    <ErrorButton> That's an error! </ErrorButton>
```

How can I use styled-components with Storybook without adding those variants as class/className? Should it be used together? Should I have different components for each variant I want to use (size, color, etc), like `</ BigErrorButton>` and `</ SmallErrorButton>`?

Thanks!